# simple php: unable to execute C++ from php

Tags: php, c++, linux, shell, web

Newbie (PHP). Trying to call a C++ executable (a.out) from php. but unable to do so. Can run the a.out script in terminal as shown in pic here. Using netbeans and mac.

My PHP Code:

[image: My PHP Code]

My Terminal Output:

[image: Terminal output]

My Code output:

[image: My Code output]

My C++ Source File:

[image: C++ Source File]

Output after using escapeshellargument:

[image: escapshell]

My PHP Version:

[image: PHP Version]

Read Permissions for the file :

[image: Read Permissions]

Comment: Are you in the right directory? What does `echo getcwd();` show?

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Are the files involved in your parameters readable by the user as which your web server or php-fpm is running?

Comment: @minitech My first command in the php script checks the contents of the current directory (in web browser output) and the terminal is executing the command correctly.

Comment: @mhall I now have an attachment that shows the PHP version that I am using.

Comment: @FrederickZhang I now have an attachment that shows the permissions for the requested file. They can be read, I think.

Comment: Pardon my C++ coding skills. I am a newbie to that, too.

Comment: Please don't use screenshot but use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a.out` may be expecting exactly three parameters, but is only given two. The third parameter will be empty in the `exec` call.

Try this:

```
$param3 = escapeshellarg(""); // Will make it "''" => empty but existing to a.out
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made the changes. Size of array is 1 now but still I don't see any output. I have also attached the source file for a.out.

Comment: I also tried escapshellarg for param1 and param2 but still I don't see any output like in the terminal window. Good thing is now it shows that size of array is 1.